# How to send email with sender name using AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am currently using AWS SDK to send mails:

```java
  // from: noreply@domain.com
  public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String htmlBody) {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Sending Mail from: %s, to: %s, with subject: %s", from, to, subject));
    try {
      AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecret);
      AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
              .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
              .build();

      SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withDestination(new Destination().withToAddresses(to))
              .withMessage(new Message()
                      .withBody(new Body().withHtml(new Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(htmlBody)))
                      .withSubject(new Content().withCharset("UTF-8").withData(subject)))
              .withSource(from);

      client.sendEmail(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error(String.format("Error while sending email: %s", e.getMessage()));
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageEnum.FAILED_TO_SEND_AN_EMAIL.name());
    }
  }
```

The method works fine but the email is sent as:
[image: The current version]

But I am expecting the email to be sent with the sender name so that it can be displayed like:
[image: The expected version]

Does anyone have any idea on how to send an email including the sender name? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified your email address https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email- ?addresses.html

Comment: @akortex Yes, I have

Comment: Try setting from as `from = new InternetAddress("sender@example.com", "Sender Name").toString()` and to set with source `.withSource(from);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check documentation of [`SendEmailRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/model/SendEmailRequest.html#withSource-java.lang.String-) you can find out that it supports standard way to define friendly name in email:

> source - The email address that is sending the email. This email address must be either individually verified with Amazon SES, or from a domain that has been verified with Amazon SES. For information about verifying identities, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide.
> If you are sending on behalf of another user and have been permitted to do so by a sending authorization policy, then you must also specify the SourceArn parameter. For more information about sending authorization, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide.
> Amazon SES does not support the SMTPUTF8 extension, as described in RFC6531. For this reason, the local part of a source email address (the part of the email address that precedes the @ sign) may only contain 7-bit ASCII characters. If the domain part of an address (the part after the @ sign) contains non-ASCII characters, they must be encoded using Punycode, as described in RFC3492. The sender name (also known as the friendly name) may contain non-ASCII characters. These characters must be encoded using MIME encoded-word syntax, as described in RFC 2047. MIME encoded-word syntax uses the following form: =?charset?encoding?encoded-text?= .

So that string should look like:
`John Doe <johndoe@example.com>`

[`InternetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) can be used for this, but you need to pay attention on encoding restrictions that `SendEmailRequest` has for `from` argument

```
request.withSource((new InternetAddress("mail@example.com", "Your Name")).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old Amazon Simple Email Service API (V1). For best practice, use the **SES Java V2 API**. V2 packages always start with **software.amazon...**

The Amazon SDK team strongly recommends moving from V1 to V2:

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

You can set this information (sender name) by setting the **SendEmailRequest** object properly.

Here is the [Java  V2 SES example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/ses/src/main/java/com/example/ses/SendMessageEmailRequest.java).

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.SesClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Message;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.Body;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

public class SendMessageEmailRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <sender> <recipient> <subject> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    sender - an email address that represents the sender. \n"+
                "    recipient -  an email address that represents the recipient. \n"+
                "    subject - the  subject line. \n" ;

          if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
             System.exit(1);
           }

        String sender = "foo@testmail.com" ;//args[0];
        String recipient = "foo@testmail.com" ;//args[1];
        String subject = "Test Email"; //args[2];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SesClient client = SesClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        // The email body for non-HTML email clients
        String bodyText = "Hello,\r\n" + "See the list of customers. ";

        // The HTML body of the email
        String bodyHTML = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body>" + "<h1>Hello!</h1>"
                + "<p> See the list of customers.</p>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

        try {
            send(client, sender, recipient, subject, bodyText, bodyHTML);
            client.close();
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void send(SesClient client,
                            String sender,
                            String recipient,
                            String subject,
                            String bodyText,
                            String bodyHTML
    ) throws MessagingException {

        Destination destination = Destination.builder()
                .toAddresses(recipient)
                .build();

        Content content = Content.builder()
                .data(bodyHTML)
                .build();

        Content sub = Content.builder()
                .data(subject)
                .build();

        Body body = Body.builder()
                .html(content)
                .build();

        Message msg = Message.builder()
                .subject(sub)
                .body(body)
                .build();

        SendEmailRequest emailRequest = SendEmailRequest.builder()
                .destination(destination)
                .message(msg)
                .source(sender)
                .build();

        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES " + "using the AWS SDK for Java...");
            client.sendEmail(emailRequest);

        } catch (SesException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
 }
```